# when installing Android Studio in ubuntu 15,run studio.sh,but it report "cannot open shared object file"

Tags: android

I install an Android develop environment in ubuntu15,after installing JDK,and SDK tools,run studio.sh,it reports some error info:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m;    support was removed in 8.0

Start Failed: Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:92)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/xhk/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXtst.so.6: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1842)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1668)
at java.awt.Cursor.<clinit>(Cursor.java:195)
at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.<clinit>(HTMLEditorKit.java:623)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:96)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:72)
... 6 more


Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:593)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:248)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:234)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:224)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:95)
```

but libawt_xawt.so, libXtst.so.6 have existed,PATH has been set

```
$ locate libawt_xawt.so
/home/xhk/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so
$ locate libXtst.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0
$ echo$PATH/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/xhk/java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin:/home/xhk/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin:/home/xhk/android/android-sdk-linux:/home/xhk/android/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/xhk/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

How can i fix it? o.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have installed the 32 bit version of the java SDK as indicated by this line:

```
/home/xhk/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so
```

But your system is a 64 bit system as indicated by these lines

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0
```

There are two solutions. The first is to install the 64 bit version of the java jdk. The second is to install the 32 bit version of the libXtst

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
```

I would prefer the first option